# Excel vba How do I check in a specified row except the specified cell is empty

Tags: excel, vba

This is part of the code.I want to display the values(strings separated by comma) that the user enters(using input box) in a cell that is also mentioned by the user. So for the first time execution I want to insert a row when the user mentions a specific range/ cell. Then insert the values the user mentioned in the exact cell where they want it to be inserted. For the next time execution I want the values to be appended to the same cell seperated by a comma.
I started with this code:

```
Case 14
Dim Rang As String
Terms = InputBox("Please enter words, if more than one string seperate by comma and space", "Need Input", 1)
Rang = InputBox("Please enter cell where you want the terms to be displayed like C2,D2 ", "Need Input", 0, 8)
Range(Rang).EntireRow.Insert
Range(Rang).Value = Terms
.....
```

For eg when the user mentions terms: turn, signal
for Rang they say f2
Second row is created and then in cell f2: turn, signal is displayed.
For the next time execution I want the values to be appended to the previous one separated by comma and space. With the current code it is creating a new row each time and adding the value to the new cell.I can ask the user to mention the same cell value each time if that helps. I thought of using the following code to append the values.

```
Range(Rang).Value=Range(Rang).Value & ", " &Terms
```

How do I check if the specified row except the specified cell is empty so that I dont have to insert the specified entire row but append the values accordingly

Comment: What is the point of inserting a whole new row instead of just writing the values to the cell?

Comment: @John I want to insert these values below the column names which might vary sometimes the column names are in first row sometimes 3rd row. Thus I am expecting the user to input the cell. I dont want to mess up with the data that is avaliable in the excel sheet. Thus want a separate row.